# How read/write file in sdcard using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems, android-external-storage

I trying write/read file on sdcard using PhoneGap. Reading [Android File System](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout) I test cordova.file.dataDirectory, cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory but this give me access to:

1. file:///data/user/0//files
2. file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/
3. file:///storage/emulated/0/

The question, I can read/write this directories but I need leave this file public, out of sandbox.

So, any idea about how do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 4.4, apps are restricted to read-only access outside of their sandbox. The only place the app has write access to is within its sandboxed areas:

- in /data/ area, e.g. file:///data/data/your.app.id/
- in internal /sdcard area, e.g. file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/your.app.id/
- in external SD card area (if present) e.g. file:///storage/emulated/1/Android/data/your.app.id/ - note: this is not accessible via cordova-plugin-file

It is not possible for an app to write to other locations outside of these sandboxed areas.